# Google Drive API download jpg

Tags: php, download, google-drive-api, jpeg

I am trying to download a google drive jpg using php to the server so that it is saved as a usuable jpg, such as when it is manually downloaded.

I can get the getWebContentLink from the filemeta and save 'a' file with extension .jpg:

```
$filemeta = $this->service->files->get($id,[
    "fields"=>"*"
]);
$filename = public_path().'/test.jpg';
$url=$filemeta->getWebContentLink();
file_put_contents($filename, fopen($url, 'r'));
```

however this is not a true jpg and indeed cannot be displayed using an `<img src="/test.jpg" />` element.

**Setup:**

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->getClient();
        $this->service= new Google_Service_Drive($this->client);
    }

    /**
     * @return Google_Client
     * @throws \Google_Exception
     */
    protected function getClient() {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
        //20200521$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
       $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY);


       // https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
        $client->setAuthConfig(base_path().'/apicredentials/google/credentials.json');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

        // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
        // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        // time.
        $tokenPath = base_path().'/apicredentials/google/token.json';
        if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
            $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        }

        // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
            if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
            } else {
                // Request authorization from the user.
                $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
                printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
                print 'Enter verification code: ';
                $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

                // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
                $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

                // Check to see if there was an error.
                if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                    throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
                }
            }
            // Save the token to a file.
            if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
                mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
            }
            file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
        }
        $this->client=$client;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Issue and workaround:

In order to retrieve the file content with `webContentLink` from outside, it is required to use the access token or the file is required to be shared publicly. So in your script, I think that the created file is the HTML data of the login page.

So how about the following workaround?

1. Download the file content with `webContentLink` using the access token.
2. At first, share publicly the file on Google Drive. Then, download the file content using your current script.
3. Directly download the file content using Drive API. In this case, the modified script is as follows. And if you are using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly` as the scope, please modify to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`.

   ```
   $content = $this->service->files->get($id, array("alt" => "media"));
   $filename = public_path().'/test.jpg';
   file_put_contents($filename, $content->getBody());
   ```

#### Reference:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

Comment: are these three different workarounds, particularly interested in #1 - how do get an actual img download using token. Re #2 I did not really want to play around with permissions, as it would be 3 calls - to make public/download/revert permissions.With #3 not sure how or where to change scope.

Comment: @Datadimension Thank you for replying. From your replying, can I see your whole script? Because when I saw it, I thought the modification points of your script for the pattern 1 and 3 might be able to be proposed. From your replying and question, I cannot understand about the scopes and the script of the authorization. I have to apologize for this. If you can do, please add it to your question. By the way, when the pattern 1 is used, 2 API calls are required. On the other hand, when the pattern 3 is used, only one API call is required. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: thanks for help so far, have updated question with set, and you answer with attempt at 3 so far

Comment: @Datadimension Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your script, I could understand that you are using `Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_READONLY` as the scope. I think that in this scope, you can directly use the pattern 3. So can you test the pattern 3 using your `$this->service`?

Comment: @Datadimension Now I noticed your edit request for my answer. When you add more information, please add it to your question. Please don't add to the answer. By the way, about `The user has not granted the app`, I think that your refresh token and access token are required to be refreshed. So could you please reauthorize the scope and test it again?

Comment: @Datadimension If you cannot understand how to reauthorize the scopes, the method for reauthorizing is as follows. 1. Delete the file of `token.json`. 2. Run the script and reauthorize by retrieving the authorization code using the browser.

Comment: Edits to answer reversed, sorry !!

Comment: @Datadimension No problem. I'm glad you understood it. By the way, can I ask you about your current issue?