# Download Google SpreadSheet Google API PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to download a Google Spreadsheet file but I am getting an error every time. I was basically doing what it is written here: [how to write a google drive download file to a directory using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449923/how-to-write-a-google-drive-download-file-to-a-directory-using-php) , But I am getting: `Warning: Undefined property: Google_Service_Sheets::$files in`  when I run the following code:

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('GoogleSheets');
$client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE]);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

$fileId = mySpreadSheetID;

// Retrieve filename.
$file = $service->files->get($fileId);
$fileName = 'Test_'.time();

// Download a file.
$content = $service->files->get($fileId, array("alt" => "media"));
$handle = fopen("./".$fileName, "w+");
while (!$content->getBody()->eof()) { 
    fwrite($handle, $content->getBody()->read(1024));
}
fclose($handle);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do it that way if its a binary type file for a Google sheet you will need to [export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) it. Also you should be creating a drive service and not a sheets service.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$response = $service->files->export($createdFile->id, 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', array('alt' => 'media' ));
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();    
file_put_contents('test.xlsx',$content);
```

Comment: Can I export to the .xlsx file? I need the style to be preserved and in that example that you shoe me it seems the file created would be in .csv therefore no style

Comment: sure just change the mime type, try that.

Comment: Thank you so much. Btw, just one more questions, How do you find out that you need to use `'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'`  ?

Comment: You can find the correct export mime types here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/ref-export-formats